# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I had got an `iPad` application.The `ViewContrtoller.xib` has got an `UIImageView` in it. The `UIImage` of the `UIImageView` is set through `Interface Builder`. When I run the application in simulator everything is fine. But when I am trying to run it in `iPad` the `UIImage` is not loaded. The message that I am getting is:

> HexaPuzzle1.0[3259:207] Could not load the "start.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.yourcompany.HexaPuzzle1-0"
>       2010-12-17 10:57:27.221 HexaPuzzle1.0[3259:207] HexaPuzzle loaded

Any help would be appreciated and will be a great help for me.

Comment: Make sure the image is included in your bundle. If you ran it in the simulator with it, but accidentally removed it before running on the device, the simulator could still have it but the device wouldn't.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw:  The image is already in the bundle and I haven't removed it.

Comment: Try by remove the old build in the device and install new build

Comment: @Satya: I had removed old build removed the image and reloaded with new image. Then also the same problem persist.

Comment: I think, you may have given the wrong image name in the code, that means you need to give exact name(case sensitive). iPhone device is case sensitive, but simulator is not.

Comment: @Satya: Not at all. The image name is correct.exact match. No difference in the case.After all image is placed in image view through interfacebuilder. Not by code.I had already checked for this possibility. Thanks  for the interest shown by you.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11209174/78336

Comment: Here is another possible solution for iOS 8 - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26852714/3696772

Answer (score 25):

The issue has been rectified.
Problem was with the image format. When the image has been edited and saved as **PNG-24** everything goes fine.
The application now runs smoothly in simulator and device.

Thanks for all friends who suggested a solution and tried to helped me.

Regards,
Rupesh R Menon

Comment: I was having the same problem and this worked for me. Apparently something went wrong the first time I saved the png. I resaved it to a different filename and then renamed it. It is working now. Thanks!

Comment: The problem for me I don't have a image file with that name. And I don't use that file in my nib file at all. How can I find which file is using this image file?

Comment: In my case, the problem was that the @2x image had a diferente name: a non-capitalized letter.

Comment: I've put the jpg image to the Images.xcassets. And it worked in simulator but not on the device. Does it mean that iOS doesn't handle jpg images ?

Comment: I've solved it editing all my JPG images and saving them in PNG-24 but I'm sure that it have to be any way to load JPG images. In this [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cocoaheadsau/gMyuu0Nt3yY) some people say that is enough to add the `.jpg` extension in the Interface Buider and in Images.xcassets but it didn't work for me...

Answer (score 12):

I know it's very late, but this is a solution that also works in Xcode 5, and therefore likely to be useful to people who have this problem in the future.

I have seen a lot of questions like this on the web but none of them seems to have one clear answer. This is, as far as I know, the solution for this problem:

- Go to the image in Xcode (no need to re-add or re-generate the
  image)
- click "show the file inspector"
- Make sure the checkbox in the category "Target Membership" is checked. the test check box does not have to be checked to make your app load the image.

**The target membership tab looks like this:**

[image]

if this is already the case, you are working with a broken or damaged file. to rule this out, check if another app (like photoshop) can open your image.

This should do it, hope it helps!

Comment: @Imagine digital i click on show in inspector the image is not opened please tell me the solution

Comment: Make sure the image is selected in the navigator when you click the "show file inspector" tab. once you have clicked that tab, make sure you check the checkbox named "Target Membership"

Comment: There is no "Target Membership" category in the inspector when I have an image selected.

Comment: Thanks @Imaginedigital. My images are in one of those pesky blue folders. Not sure if that has anything to do with the images not loading for me.

Comment: You may want to select the blue folder and make sure the "Target Membership" is selected for that. If not, try to add the images separately instead of the entire folder.

Answer (score 5):

When dragging your *start.png* file into your project, did you check this option?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the interest taken. You mean to add to the image to target? It's already there.

Comment: This has already done. Image is already copied to destination group's folder and it is also there in target. I think some other issue. Any way thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error in the simulator after upgrading to Xcode 7 / iOS 9 and opening an existing project. The image was present and named correctly, within an XCAssets package.

Turns out the problem was with a parameter within the XCAssets package.

Changing `Render As` from *Default* to *Original Image* solved the problem:

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue, but I'm not sure what is the root cause. Do you know why "Default" doesn't work?

Comment: No @tsr, I haven't had chance to check yet. I did notice that some "Default" images in the project already weren't affected, but I haven't spotted the pattern yet.

Comment: Solved the problem. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem before. The png file format is not right. Try re-generate the png image file and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, and the message I got was "could not load the "(null)" image referenced... which means I could not look for the image. Very frustrating. In the end it became a trial and error exercise of going through every xib and storyboard looking for potential conflicts. I finally found it - I had specified a "Selected Image" for a tab bar item which was not needed. As soon as I got rid of that the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

None of these things work for me. I created a new folder in the projects where I placed the pictures. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed when I changed "add folder reference..." to "add group..." when I import the images to my project. I'd prefer to have folders with live updating, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Had an image on a XIB (which is replaced by the correct one in code).  After finishing this XIB, I renamed the images.  So XIB was now referencing a non-existent image.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another potential cause of this problem: If you upgraded to XCode 5 and use both the image asset catalog and "normal" images copied to your project (like you did prior XCode 5). If you then have images with identical names (e.g. "dog.png" and a image set called "dog") it might work in your storyboard and in the simulator, but you'll get this message when run on a real device (where the image will not be shown).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the images directly to the Resources directory (not in a sub folder)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the resource isn't too big to be handle.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error message with the name of the picture, you can search it inside your project and `xCode` will display immediately the `UIImageView` with the wrong picture inside `UIStoryboard`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is included in your Target Membership

1. Select your "Images.xcassets" file in the file Inspector
2. Open File Inspector (cmd + opt + 1)
3. Select your target membership (Usually 1st line)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the cause was very different. I was using image sets in the Asset Catalog that varied based on the device idiom: iPad or iPhone.

The framework target they were being added to had been accidentally marked as as having a deployment device type of `iPhone`, so the images weren't showing up on iPads - they weren't even being copied into the `.car` file in the framework.

Setting the deployment device type to `Universal`, as it should have been, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was getting error until I put the image in the Assets.xcassets