# Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle running on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> SplitView[1290:307] Could not load the "canary04.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "xx.co.mycompany.ipad.SplitView"

I only get the error when running on the device.  There are no problems running in simulator.

I am using the image directly in interface builder with an UIImageView.

EDIT: I have added a different new image to a different nib and that works no problems.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this on the simulator (case in-sensitive) or the device itself (case sensitive)?

Comment: Only happens on device never simulator

Comment: middaparka answers didn't solve your issue why would you be marking it as the answer. It's misleading for others who have the same issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5842298/1002338 this is the right answer

Comment: @Mona Hopefully the OP will mark the correct answer. (Although the question is pretty long in the tooth that said.)

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11209174/78336

Comment: This issue may occur with Google + integrating with iOS too. Even though the GooglePlus.bundle is inside the place just as @PeterTheill says I had to drag and drop the image which is already inside the GooglePlus.bundle. That will solve the issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The filesystem on iOS devices is case sensitive, so it's quite possibly a case issue. (Mac OS X is generally case in-sensitive, hence you've not seen this issue in the simulator.)

As such, check that you're using the same case in the code as the filename itself.

Comment: I am referencing the image directing in interface builder

Comment: @TheLearner OK. Have you tried deleting the app off the device and then re-installing it? (There are sometimes issues with resources not being "pushed" to the app.)

Comment: @middaparka yep have tried that I have restored the device even.

Comment: @TheLearner Must confess I'm out of ideas then. :-( I presume this is a "standard" PNG? (Not some weird format or anything?)

Comment: @middaparka yeah it seems to be yes.

Comment: @TheLearner Another thought - was size is the PNG file in terms of the width, height & resolution (dpi)? Also, what's its filesize?

Comment: @middaparka 41 KB PNG 480 x 321.  I just added a completely seperate image to a different nib and it worked so really not sure

Comment: @middaparka - would you mind deleting my question as I have not solved the problem with any of these answers unfortunately

Comment: @TheLearner That's not the way Stack Overflow works. You question will still show up as un-solved, so I'd be tempted to wait a few days before you give up hope.

Answer (score 129):

It might not be added to your Target and in XCode 4 you can do it like this:

- In your Project View, click your project name
- Select your target and select "Build Phases" tab
- Drag your image file into your "Copy Bundle Resources" section

That fixed it for me.

Comment: This is the stuff they never teach in books.
Lesson: Always check "Copy Bundle Resources" if you are having image issues

Comment: You saved my day! 
In my case, I was loading images to UITableViewCell programmatically and I wasn't getting any warnings/errors at all, neither was I seeing my images...

Answer (score 20):

Do you have the image in a referenced folder in XCode (blue folder)?  If so you have to include the folder name in the image path, something like "Images/canary04.png"

Comment: I had this same problem and fixed it by including the bundle name and folder name in the image path. In my case, it was:
UIImage *logoutNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/LogoutNormal@2x.png"];

Comment: Thanks for answer this has saved my day.

Answer (score 14):

## The easy way

<kbd>1</kbd> Simply do a [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) in command shell to find the string of the referenced image:

```
grep -R 'canary04.png' YourMainDirectoryFolder/*
```

---

<kbd>2</kbd> It will give you (for example) an output like this:

```
YourProject/en.lproj/YourViewController.xib: 

<textField borderStyle="roundedRect" background="canary04.png" id="19">
```

<kbd>3</kbd> You now know which nib file and which element it is. Just go in the file and remove the reference.

Comment: this is what I needed. After moving to storyboard, it was still loading the nib, which was referencing the old image that didn't exist anywhere in teh project.

Comment: It Helped me for removing the image name in the UIImage View which is no longer exist in the project. I could find out the Xib which caused this warning.

Answer (score 8):

1. Delete the blue folder where the image is.
2. Import again and select "Copy items if needed".
3. Select "Create Groups" NOT folders

Answer (score 5):

Save image as PNG-24. It works for me

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to check it from your storyboard, or nib. Open it as Source Code:

[image]

Then "Find" the image name in it, see if it exists but already invalid in your project, probably you have deleted or changed its name, and now it doesn't seem valid.

[image]

Comment: This helped me. I searched for that image, and found that it was set as background to a button, but the image was deleted. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 4):

Have you included the file in the target?  Right-click on your Target in Xcode, select Get Info and choose the "Targets" group along the top.  Make sure your intended target(s) are checked.

Good Luck.

**EDIT:**
The text above should have read Right-click the **file (canary04.png)** in Xcocde and select Get Info...

Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I don't see any targets group

Comment: This is an old answer referring to an older version of the IDE.  Now you would just select the file in the project and look at the File Inspector on the right of the window.  From there you can easily see if the file is included in the Target you are expecting to see it in.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem when I upgraded to Xcode 4.4.1.  I found that although I had deleted the images (and corresponding buttons, etc.) in the storyboards, there was still mention of them in my storyboard files (in a tabBarItems field).  I manually commented them out (), Product -> Clean, and I didn't get the errors any more.

I knew there must be bogus references in the storyboard as I had previously deleted my TabBar and the current App worked without problems, just with annoying messages in the console.

Comment: Is there anyway to delete all outdated references in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. try to

- clean
- build and run

it worked with me

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was because Photoshop wasn't saving my files correctly.  In the file save dialog I was clicking on myfile.png in an attempt to overwrite that file, and it was saving the file with a png extension, but in photoshop format.

I had to make sure to actually change the file format to PNG before clicking on the file I wanted to overwrite, thus saving in actual png file, thus being readable by iOS.  Interestingly, interface builder showed my psd-as-png files just fine.

More generically, make sure your file is, in fact, in the format you think it is and that iOS is therefore expecting.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 :**

In my case I had copied folder containing images and even *checked "Destination : copy items if needed"*. However it has not been added to "Copy Bundle Resources" of "Build Phases".

You can add images as follows :

1. Select *Targets*
2. Select *"Build Phases"* tab
3. Select *"Copy Bundle Resources*"
4. Click on *"+"* (Plus) button just beneath it
5. Locate images and add it

[image: Screenshot for solution 1]

**Solution 2 :**

*Delete images* by selecting "Move to thrash". Again *add images* in your project with "Destination : copy items if needed" checked.

```
Note : Make sure that you add images in Assets.xcassets folder and not outside it.
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error too. I will describe my scenario:

I have a subdirectory "img" which has some png's in it.
One of these png is "ic_timeprogress_000.png"

In the storyboard (visual designer) I had an imageView and the image was set to "ic_timeprogress_000.png" (not programatically). The designer showed the imageView correctly:

[image: imageView in subdirectory]

Although when running the app, the error was thrown.

So in the storyboard I changed (I insist: not programatically) from "ic_timeprogress_000.png" to "img/ic_timeprogress_000.png", which lead to not showing correctly the image in the designer but showing correctly when running (no error)

[image: imageView in subdirectory]

Although I alter `imageView.image` programatically, so this "initial image" isn't ever used.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that `canary04.png` exists in your project, and that it was not deleted.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I saved the image as .jpg and changed the name to .png (was still in jpg format). It worked with simulator

Answer (score 1):

Check your image name. If **it contains some spaces then image will show while running in simulator but not in the device.**  While running it checks Case sensitive name etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different problem in iOS 8. In my case the problem was that I selected Device Specific for the image set, and then selected iPad. Changing this back to Universal fixed the problem.

This setting can be found in the images.xcassets file, in the third column show the attributes inspector for the image set.

In this case the images wont be displayed in the storyboard or NIB file even if you have added them to images.xcassets. They also wont show in the simulator or device.

Comment: I had this. xCode 7.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this issue when I was trying to set image of an imageView on Interface Builder (.xib) file.

(I was using Image Assets)

I've had 2 images with `theImage.jpeg` and `theImage@2x.jpg`
Interface Builder could be able to display true images at compile time with these `jpg / jpeg` formats. But I've got this error in the runtime:

```
Could not load the "theImage" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "org.etc.etc"
```

Then I changed my image files formats to `.png` and it worked!

Try this solution too if you have different formats for images you try to set.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the problem that jpeg files cannot be loaded successfully, however I solved it without changing them to png format: for example, if you have an image named **"bg.jpg"**, don't use **"bg"** in storyboard (this name is listed in the dropdown selection list), instead you should explicitly write **"bg.jpg"** in the name field.

For programming based image view, I guess using .jpg extension like `[UIImage imageNamed:@"xx.jpg"]` should also work (I did't test though).

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project and make sure the info.plist matches the xx.co.mycompany.ipad.SplitView

Answer (score 0):

Check the image name. Then check to see if you can open the image itself in paint or photoshop.  If the image was created in photoshop and there were layers sometimes there is some conflict with the .png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, if your images are inside sub-folders, you need to choose "Create groups for subfolders" Option when you copy the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with Xcode 5, and it seems "Combine high resolution artwork" is the culprit. I opened the app bundle, and all the images were *.tiff, which caused the image to "not be found" :S

**FIX**:

Open project settings, and search in the top for "combine". Change that setting to NO.

[image]

For some reason, everyone is missing this essential fix.

Comment: That's for OS X.  The question is tagged as `iPhone`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all images where displaying fine on devices with >iOS 7 but not with iOS 6.1.
The solution was that iOS7 is case sensitive but iOS 6.1 wasn't for me. I had images named like "myImageName" and also named "myimagename" witch leads my old iPhone 3 to be unable to display these images.
So renaming them solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried each and every answer here and nothing, so here's another glitch, your icon name cannot have dots (.) because if it does (and Xcode allows you to do that!) while the icons show well in storyboard, they won't load either in the simulator or the device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after you set the button's image, you changed the image's name.

Answer (score 0):

2015 - Still having this problem. I was referencing an image that no longer existed in one of tabbed buttons.

**Solution:**
Simply inspect all your buttons, UIImage etc. and make sure that the image that you are referencing actually exists within your project.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I accidentally added another Image set to Asset Catalog file. I renamed it after I realised the mistake, but it doesn't seem to work.

Removing the file and adding it again solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is making sure the file's owner in interface builder has a "view" outlet.

From IB, select file's owner from "Placeholders", then in "Connections Inspector" make sure the view outlet in connected to the main view of current XIB.

This happened because i removed the main view at some point and forgot to reconnect my new view.

Hope it helps somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was the image format. They were 'jpg' files, while Xcode was expecting 'png' files. Changing the file format fixed the issue.

Comment: yes, using the xcassets in Xcode, you can load file in jpg format and using this image in Storyboard you not have problem, but only at run time not will be possible to load splash image.

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same problem because i edited image in photoshop and saved as a psd format make sure you save your photoshoped images in jpg or png format in my case that was the problem hope it helps thanks

Answer (score 0):

JPEG format does gives this error in release mode in iOS. This might happens while, XCode optimizes the code for release. Try replacing the image with JPEG and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My trouble was none of the above. I put the iconFolder in Xcode project's folder.

When I imported it, selected  "Copy items if needed" and "Create Groups".

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, adding the file extension to the end of the image title is what solved it for me.

it was referencing "canary04" bc thats what I titled the image, but once I changed the image title to the title of the image itself (canary04.png) it was solved.