# What is Wrong with My Way of Changing UIBUtton Background Image?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, png

Let's look at this picture:

[image]

The left arrow shows that the button background have changed in Interface Builder, yet it's still white on the simulator (and iPhone).

The right arrow shows that I have changed the background image.

So how come the background image doesn't change?

Also what is the background parameter on that interface builder anyway? The reason I ask is when you programatically set the background image you need to specify the state.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Hint: the image is too big but you can use ctrl + in firefox to zoom in :D

Note: I added:

```
  UIImage * imgFilterBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filter-bar.png"];
    [self.ChangeFilter setBackgroundImage:imgFilterBar forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

in viewDidLoad

and it still doesn't work.

I got this warning:
2012-10-10 18:29:59.929 BadgerNew[29833:c07] Could not load the "filter-bar.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

What does it mean? Am I doing  [UIImage imageNamed:@"filter-bar.png"]; correctly? The file is in my project.

[image]

Comment: did you check if the file is inside the Bundle?BuildPhases->Copy Bundle resources. check if this file is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by Kendall in [Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle running on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853808/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-running-on-device) brought me enligthenment.

The issue is I use reference folder (the blue folder). If I do that I need to mention the folder name, which is a mess.

So I just copy the whole thing to resources. Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

If you want background image on Button use the image option above background image option.

Comment: I want the text on the button to keep being seen.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try setting the UIButton image instead of UIButton backgroundimage?

```
[self.ChangeFilter setImage:imgFilterBarforState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a tittle to the button to see the name. Check the different tittle color and size, because of that probably you can not see the tittle. If this is not possible, add a uilabel in the button