# Why won't my image load when i run my app?

Tags: ios, image

I have an image view with an image selected as the background. Every time i run the app the console says

```
'could not load image from nib'.
```

It only does this with one photo which is the same size as the iPhone 5 resolution. if i change the photo it works normally. Why does it do this and how can i fix it?

Also if n one knows what i'm on about could you tell me how to make a background image in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume with your first approach you are trying to set the image to the imageView via the Interface Builder. In this case do check if the filenames are correct and also do a clean build to assure that any old versions of the image are not there in your bundle. Remember that the filenames are case-sensitive. Else, do have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5842298/1740354

Secondly, you could set it programmatically as follows:
Here you will be creating the imageview in the code inside the viewDidLoad method hence you will have to remove the imageview you have added via the interface builder.

```
UIImageView *imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageFilename.png"]];

[imageview1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; // This will decide the size of your imageview.

[self.view addSubview:imageview1]; // This has to be added in order to see the imageview in your view.
```

Also, if you want to want to use the imageview that you have created in the Interface builder, then you will have to create an IBOutlet from the nib to your viewcontroller and then use the same name as follow:

```
[self.imageIBOutlet setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageFilename.png"]];
```

where imageIBOutlet will be your IBOutlet for your imageView from the nib to the viewcontroller and "yourImageFilename.png" is the filename of your image file.

Comment: I am getting an error saying unused variable imageview1?

Comment: Have updated the answer with the two additional lines to set the frame (size) of your imageview and also to add it to your main view that the app is currently displaying.