# iOS 7 : could not load image referenced from nib in the bundle with identifier

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios7.1

I have found a some strange behavior on referencing image from my image asset directory. I am currently developing a static framework for other applications to consume, my framework provides some general User interface which has some image assets to be referred. My deployment target will be iOS 7.0 I failed to read a image from my framework bundle specifically in iOS 7 and got it correctly working in iOS 8.0 by make use of,

```
[UIImage imageNamed:name inBundle:[Utilities getCurrentBundle] compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

but unfortunately I failed to found equivalent method in iOS 7.0

For your kind information I have already referred following answers from Stackoverflow,

[Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198946/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-with-identifier)

[Could not load the image referenced from a nib in the bundle running on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853808/could-not-load-the-image-referenced-from-a-nib-in-the-bundle-running-on-device)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are no size classes in iOS 7

Comment: yep, that method is available only from iOS 8.0 I want a similar method for iOS 7...

Comment: you have to load images directly from your bundle

Comment: but I refered files from another static framework, so the bundle is also differebt right... so I cant use [uiimage imageNamed:]

Comment: -imageNamed: works only with main bundle. I think what you want is to get your NSBundle, then get path for image and finally create UIImage with received path.

Comment: Yes you are right Andy., I tried that too. with below code,              [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]];  But still faces issue only with iOS 7.

Comment: Did you try debugging this to find out if you access image at the wrong path? Maybe your images aren't in "Resources".

Comment: No Its still available in the specified path but the issue is only with iOS 7 which confuses me a lot....

Comment: Just make a method that checks if selector is available and uses it, otherwise craft path for bundle and load image directly. Easy.

Comment: Thanks Andy, Anyway I tried the same solution in my code but it seems not  reflected the results as expected. I simply made a call to available API for iOS 8 , and for iOS 7, I just loaded from resource path, but seems not working... Any other luck please...