# I just renamed my app and now my images can't be found. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift

I followed the steps at this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html

When I got to the final step and hit "enter", XCode crashed and now when I build my app, my Supporting Files folder can't be found.

Error:

```
2015-06-16 00:42:49.725 BK Cards[11613:3145145] Could not load the "xySection.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.test.test"
```

Also, the error message includes the original name of the app, not the new one. What is going on?

Comment: Try a clean of the project (Shift Cmd K) then rebuild

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but no luck!

Comment: Did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17487339/2091181 ?